# VBA Error 429 'ActiveX can't create application object'

Tags: vba

Hi Guyz I'm writing these lines of code with powerpoint but getting error 429

[image: Error]

pls help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListSlideInformationInExcel()
Dim i, j As Integer

Cells(1, 1).Value = "slide number"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "No. of shapes"

Dim appPower As Object
Set appPower = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Dim pPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

appPower.Visible = True

appPower.Presentations.Open "C:\Users\SUMIT\Downloads\Slide Show Demo.ppt"

For i = 1 To pPres.Slides.Count
    j = 2
    Range("A" & j).Value = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
    Range("B" & j).Value = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Name
    Range("C" & j).Value = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.Count
    j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully solve your problem but assuming power point is installed you should be able to use late bound references all the way through as follows.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListSlideInformationInExcel()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "slide number"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = "No. of shapes"

        Dim appPower As Object, pPres As Object
        Set appPower = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        appPower.Visible = True    
        Set pPres = appPower.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\SUMIT\Downloads\Slide Show Demo.ppt")
        'Other stuff
    End With  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi QHarr it didn't solve my problem. Actually when I debug the line 'For i = 1 To pPres.Slides.Count' it throws the error.I searched a lot but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: So it does open powerpoint? What is the value of ppres.Slides.Count?

Comment: It shud turn out 1 to 23 but it doesn't.

Comment: What does it do? Help me out here!

Comment: I want my code to print the slide number,slide's name,the number of shapes each slide has on the excel sheet.On the line 'pPres.slides.count' it shud return 23 as it is going to be a loop that runs from 1 to 23 but at that line it throws error.I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: And the error thrown is the cannot create ActiveX? That doesn't seem right. That line has nothing to do with ActiveX. There is nothing wrong with that line of code in terms of getting the slide count.